# how to increase and decrease an image width time to time through javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use the following javascript code but it's not correctly work like beating heart:-

```
<script>         
     var y = document.getElementById("p2");
     var x = document.getElementById('myImg');
     setInterval(function(){
                x.height = "110";
                x.width="120"; 
                setInterval(function(){
                            x.height = "98";
                            x.width="107";
                            },3000);
                },2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not so clear what you want to achieve but ... if you want to alternate just from one size to another, than the following example might help you :

```js
var y = document.getElementById("p2");
var x = document.getElementById('myImg');

var state = true;

var timerId; // do window.clearTimeout(timerId) to stop de alternation

function alternate(){
  x.height = state ?  110 : 98;
  x.width= state ? 120 : 107; 
  state = !state;
  timerId = window.setTimeout(alternate, 1000);
}

alternate();
```

```html
<p id="p2"></p>
<img id="myImg" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" />
```

Comment: it is recommended to use `requestAnimationFrame` when setting an elements visual property so that it is in sync with the painting phase of the browser, otherwise it can cause a replaint.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sinus and an animated loop. Start the loop at the intervals you set. Just make sure the animation loop has time to finish before it is restarted. You can instead of using transforms as here, use CSS width and height.

```js
var img = document.querySelector("img"),
    style = img.style;                                  // use styles

setInterval(animateHeart, 1100);                        // interval to animate

function animateHeart() {

  var time = 0,                                         // time for sine function
      rate = 0.2,                                       // speed of sine function
      radius = 0.5;                                     // added to 100% of its scale
  
  (function loop() {                                    // inner loop
    var scale = 1 + Math.abs(Math.sin(time) * radius);  // calc scale
    time += rate;
    if (time >= Math.PI*2) {
      style.transform =                                 // reset scale
        style.webkitTransform = "scale(1,1)";
      return
    }

    // set CSS transform to scale smoothly (alt. use width/height)
    style.transform = 
      style.webkitTransform = "scale(" + scale + "," + scale + ")";

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);                        // loop animation
  })(); 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcAtB.png">
```

Comment: Nice but I want to complete this animation by changing width and height time to time with javascript.There is an alternate method also in which changing two different size same images time to time.

Comment: @sandeep_1994, document in the initial question what you want to achive and not in comments.